# Listbox selection events (LBN_SELCHANGE and LBN_DBLCLK) not firing

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a listbox control like this:

```
HWND hAvailable = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"Listbox", NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL |
    LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL | LBS_SORT,
    0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_AVAILABLELIST,
    hInst, NULL);
```

and listening for events in my callback function, under WM_COMMAND like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
int wmId, wmEvent;

switch (message) {
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

    switch (wmId) {
    case IDC_AVAILABLELIST:
        // We get here, with LBN_SETFOCUS and LBN_KILLFOCUS
        if (wmEvent == LBN_SELCHANGE || wmEvent == LBN_DBLCLK) {
            // Never gets here!
        }

    [ ... ]
```

The issue is that when I change the selection, I can see the new item being selected but I am not receiving the appropriate event.

When I select an item, I get an LBN_SETFOCUS event, followed by an LBN_KILLFOCUS event. Any attempt to get the currently selected index  with `int idx = SendMessage(hAvailable, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);` returns -1 even though an item is in fact selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`LBN_SELCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775161.aspx) and [`LBN_DBLCLK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775153.aspx), they both say:

> This notification code is sent only by a list box that has the [`LBS_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149.aspx#LBS_NOTIFY) style.

The documentation for [`LBS_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775149.aspx#LBS_NOTIFY) says:

> LBS_NOTIFY
>   Causes the list box to send a notification code to the parent window whenever the user clicks a list box item ([`LBN_SELCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775161.aspx)), double-clicks an item ([`LBN_DBLCLK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775153.aspx)), or cancels the selection ([`LBN_SELCANCEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775159.aspx)).

You are not enabling that style on your ListBox control.

As for `LB_GETCURSEL`, it returns `LB_ERR` (-1) when there is no selection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is true. The LBS_NOTIFY needs to be in the style.

What is very peculiar about this issue is that yesterday my code did not need the LBS_NOTIFY but today it does. So weird right! I'm using Visual Studios 2019. Also, adding the LBS_NOTIFY resolved the problem only after a reboot.